# What does it mean to "pitch a response"?

Tags: vocabulary

I've tried to translate with Google and to look on [wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/enit/pitch) but I would like to have a confirmation. To pitch a response means to give an answer? Should be interpreted as a figurated "throw"?

And how to interpret sentence like: "How To Write A Pitch Email That Actually Gets Answered" or "Crafting the Perfect Email Pitch"?

Comment: In your link the example "The agency pitched for the client's business" is relevant under: **pitch for** (informal) try to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pitch is a proposal (it can also be used as a verb - *to propose*), usually in the context of a business idea.  If an inventor has created a new product or idea but doesn't have the money or resources to bring the it to market, he will *pitch* the product or idea to investors, who will hopefully provide a loan or some other type of investment.  In this context, the inventor is *pitching* the product to potential investors.  No one is actually "pitching a response," but rather the investor would respond to a pitch by either providing funding or declining the offer.

The context is typically "to pitch an idea."  If you've ever seen the American TV show *Shark Tank,* this is exactly what's happening.